# Custom Radio CSS and multiline text wrapping

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I've customised our radio buttons for a survey form using CSS. However as the standard radio button is hidden, when text is long it wraps below the replacement graphic.

We are trying to avoid editing the HTML as this part has been generated by our CRM system and to edit the HTML would mean that we would have to rebuild the entire survey from scratch and time is of the essence!

I don't have enough rep to post the image, but here's a link to it https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV79T.png

**HTML**

```
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
    <input name="q_197" value="1042" id="q_197_1042" type="radio">
    <label for="q_197_1042">I didn't get the chance to say everything I wanted 
to about stuff</label>
    </td>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
    min-width: 230px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #D1D3D4;
}

/* hide input */


input[type=radio]:empty {
    display:none;
}
/* style label */



input[type=radio]:empty + label {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    line-height:2.5em;
    text-indent:3em;
    margin:5px 1px 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}

input[type=radio]:empty + label:before {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    content:'';
    width:2em;
    background:#D3D3DB;
    border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* toggle hover */


input[type=radio]:hover:not(:checked) + label:before {
    content:'\2714';
    text-indent:.6em;
    color:#C2C2C2;
}

input[type=radio]:hover:not(:checked) + label {
    color:#888;
}

/* toggle on */


input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content:'\2714';
    text-indent:.6em;
    color:#F4F5F8;
    background-color:#0099FF;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    color:#777;
}

/* radio focus */


input[type=radio]:focus + label:before {
    box-shadow:0 0 0 3px #999;
}

textarea {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -mox-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: try displaying the label as inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just switch the `text-indent` to `padding-left`.

```
input[type=radio]:empty + label {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  text-indent: 0em; /* here */
  padding-left: 3em; /* and here */
  margin: 5px 1px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

A simple fix really.

```css
label {
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 230px;
  /* for demo purposes only */
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4;
}
/* hide input */

input[type=radio]:empty {
  display: none;
}
/* style label */

input[type=radio]:empty + label {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  text-indent: 0em;
  padding-left: 3em;
  margin: 5px 1px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
input[type=radio]:empty + label:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 2em;
  background: #D3D3DB;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* toggle hover */

input[type=radio]:hover:not(:checked) + label:before {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: .6em;
  color: #C2C2C2;
}
input[type=radio]:hover:not(:checked) + label {
  color: #888;
}
/* toggle on */

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: .6em;
  color: #F4F5F8;
  background-color: #0099FF;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  color: #777;
}
/* radio focus */

input[type=radio]:focus + label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #999;
}
textarea {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -mox-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input name="q_197" value="1042" id="q_197_1042" type="radio">
<label for="q_197_1042">I didn't get the chance to say everything I wanted to about stuff</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `input[type=radio]:empty + label` to the following and it will work just fine:

```
input[type=radio]:empty + label {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:5px 1px 5px;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 50px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}
```

Working example:

```css
label {
    min-width: 230px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #D1D3D4;
}
/* hide input */
 input[type=radio]:empty {
    display:none;
}
/* style label */
 input[type=radio]:empty + label {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:5px 1px 5px;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 50px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}
input[type=radio]:empty + label:before {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    content:'';
    width:2em;
    background:#D3D3DB;
    border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* toggle hover */
 input[type=radio]:hover:not(:checked) + label:before {
    content:'\2714';
    text-indent:.6em;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color:#C2C2C2;
}
input[type=radio]:hover:not(:checked) + label {
    color:#888;
}
/* toggle on */
 input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content:'\2714';
    text-indent:.6em;
    color:#F4F5F8;
    background-color:#0099FF;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    color:#777;
}
/* radio focus */
 input[type=radio]:focus + label:before {
    box-shadow:0 0 0 3px #999;
}
textarea {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -mox-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<td style="vertical-align: top;">
    <input name="q_197" value="1042" id="q_197_1042" type="radio">
    <label for="q_197_1042">I didn't get the chance to say everything I wanted to about stuff</label> 
</td>
```